# Establish the identity of $\cos(\pi - \theta) = - \cos(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to establish the identity but am not sure how:

$$\cos(\pi - \theta) = - \cos(\theta).$$

Comment: What facts about the cosine function do you already know? Is $\theta$ limited to $0\le\theta\le\pi$ or can it be any real number? What kind of answer do you want: geometric, using previous identities, using infinite series, using differential equations, or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it holds that: $$\cos(a – b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b)$$ 

For $a=\pi,  b=θ$ we have: $$\cos(\pi – θ) = \cos(\pi)\cos(θ) + \sin(\pi)\sin(θ)$$
Since $\sin(\pi)=0$ and $\cos(\pi)=-1$ , you have the desired result.

Comment: You can obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$ by typing \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the tip! I am not very familiar with the commands yet to be honest!

Comment: In that case, you might benefit from reading this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yet again, thank you! It seems very comprehensive and exhaustive of the subject.

Answer (score 3):

It follows from the [difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for the cosine that

$$\begin{align*}\cos{(\pi - \theta)} & ~=~ \cos{\pi}\cos{\theta} + \sin{\pi}\sin{\theta}  \\ & ~=~ -\cos{\theta} \end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\cos(\pi-\theta)=\Re e^{i(\pi-\theta)}=\Re (e^{i\pi}e^{-i\theta})=\Re (-(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)))=-\cos\theta$$

Comment: That's a more sleek way to do it. +1..